# Are there songs in the Hatsune Miku Project Diva games where the lyrics are only in English?

Tags: project-diva-series

Are there songs in the Hatsune Miku Project Diva games where the lyrics are only in English?

I know that songs like [Systematic Love](https://vocaloid.fandom.com/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%9E%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B4_(Systematic_Love)) and [After Burner](https://vocaloid.fandom.com/wiki/AFTER_BURNER) mix a little bit of English with Japanese, but they are not 100% in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DYE](https://vocaloid.fandom.com/wiki/DYE) (a Luka song) in Project Diva F has its lyrics all in English. You'll probably find it not perfectly understandable though.